# Programatically create Products/Client IDs for Google API

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

I am looking for a way to programatically create **PROJECTS** (not products, my mistake) and/or client IDs for Google APIs, I have exhausted my google-fu in locating anything pertaining to this.

Does anyone have any idea if this is even possible or do products and client ids all need to be manually created?

Matt

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about products to be included in Google Product Search and Web Search?

The Content API for Shopping allows you to programmatically create them: https://developers.google.com/shopping-content/

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm talking specifically about the OAuth projects and client IDs... I have no idea why I said products, my apologies.